# Trying to create a regex that ignores characters that are part of a group as well as words that follow a group of characteres

Tags: python, regex, pycharm, discord, discord.py

I'm new to regex and am trying to create a "Dadbot" in discord that uses regex to respond to messages in a #text-channel with "Hi, ____ I'm Dad". The problem I have is that it includes "im" as an accepted regex. This isn't bad on it's own; however, in cases where the word "him" is used, im is accepted in him. I'd like to be able to fix this regex so that:
- it reads I'm (and it's variations) 
- includes the next 3 words after I'm or until it reaches a period.

I'm not sure if I'm writing this correctly. I've used regex101.com to check my regex and my original regex was this monster: "(I'm|Im|I am|im|i am|i'm)\s+([a-zA-z]+)" and I use groups to capture the second group.

things I've tried

```py
"(I'm|Im|I am|im|i am|i'm)\s+([a-zA-z]+)"
"\bi'?m\s+(\w+)\b"
"/\bi'?m\s+(\w+)\b/gi"
```

Here's the part of the code that grabs the second group

```py
        if dadCheck.search(message.content):
            match = dadCheck.search(message.content).group(2)
            await channel.send("Hi, " + match + ". I'm Dad. ;D")
```

These are the expected results given an accepted message:

1. Hello everyone. My name is Brad and I'm a cool guy.
2. Hi, "a cool guy". I'm Dad!

Comment: Add space before and after each so it must be alone. `"( I'm | Im | I am | im | i am | i'm )\s+([a-zA-z]+)"`

Comment: OH I see now thank you both so much! I actually didn't realize word meant a regex word so that really explains a lot thank you yall. I've spent like 3 days on this one regex hahaha

Answer (score 1):

```
/(im|i am|i'm)\s(\w*\s?){1,3}/i
```

Regex is awesome and can definitely cover your use case. The above regex looks for the I'm tag and then grabs the next 1-3 words plus space in a capture group for you to reference. Strings it works with

> I'm a cool guy.
>
> Im a cool guy.
>
> i am a cool guy.
>
> i'm a cool guy.
>
> im a cool guy.
>
> im a cool guy and I like to watch football games with friends

Comment: I didn't know I could use {} like that to capture a certain # of words that's super useful thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I ultimately landed on.

```
\b(\s)?[Ii]((\sa)?|\'{0,1})[mM]\b\s+((\w*\s?)[^\.\!;:\(\)]\w+){1,3}
```

This captures all variations of I'm(im, Im, I'm, i'm,) and ignores i' am

The only problem with this is that it captures only the last iteration of the word loop. so I'll have to fix the capture groups or the algorithm I use to print the capture groups.